# Is Camunda just for Modelling BPMN or can i execute Code like REST Services

Tags: execution, bpmn, camunda

My Question is, if Camunda is just a Modelling Tool or can I execute code while the process is running ?
Like calling a REST API or something (for example if the Process gets to a Task)?

Answer (score 1):

Camunda is the process engine that runs your deployed processes. So no: it is not "just a modeling tool" (it provides the standalone camunda modeler for that).

Comment: So can I "connect" Camunda to do something, for doing for example POST-Requests (while running the deployed process). If Yes, is there any good example ?

Comment: If you are not planning to implement process steps in Java/Kotlin, you should have a look at the "camunda Run" distro. The official documentation at https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/user-guide/camunda-bpm-run/ should be a good starting point